# Can we find three odd numbers satisfying this relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

If $a^2+b^2=c^2$  and $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb N^3$ are  natural numbers. Can we find three odd numbers satisfying this relation?

Comment: Where do you see a *pair* when $a,b,c$ are *three* numbers?

Comment: How can two odd numbers add up to another odd number

Comment: That is the question actually.. It is either possible or not possible.. I am asking for if it is possible

Comment: The title says one thing, the body says another.

Answer (score 3):

The square of an odd number is still odd, and the square of an even number is even. So a number $x$ is odd if and only if its square $x^2$ is odd.

We deduce $a^2 + b^2$ is even, so $c^2$ is even, and $c$ is even. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ a, b $ be odd. Then $ a^2, b^2 $ are as well. Thus, $ a^2 + b^2 $ is even, which means that $ c^2 $ is even. Thus, $ c $ cannot be odd with $ a, b $ even.